# d3.json PHP XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: javascript, php, json, d3.js, xampp

I have a PHP script working to generate JSON data for an .htm file implementing a [force directed graph](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045).  Everything is local via XAMPP.

The PHP script needs an argument to know what data to get via the query.  When I hard-code the value of this argument into the script, everything works fine with the call from the .htm to the PHP scipt, i.e.

```
d3.json("getneighborhood.php", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;
```

But if I try to pass the argument via GET, i.e.

```
d3.json("getneighborhood.php?contact=5244", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;
```

The console shows

```
d3.v4.min.js:7 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/mail/bostock/getneighborhood.php?contact=5244. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

I gather this has something to do with loading a file, but I'm a little puzzled about why adding the argument screws things up.  Is there a way to fix?

Comment: Looks like d3.js thinks that string is a local filename. What if you prefix it with `http://domain/`?

Comment: @Alex, now I get "mailgraph2.htm:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/mail/bostock/getneighborhood.php?contact=5244. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: Sorry, edited comment when I realized its a different error.

Comment: Ok well I think if you google that header name you'll find what you need...

Comment: Adding "header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');" to the PHP script fixed it.  I still don't understand why adding the argument causes the problem tho.

Comment: Yeah seems odd. Maybe file a bug w/ d3.js.